# Splitting the working directory in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, string, array

If I do:

```
IFS="/" read -ra PARTS
```

And type in a path manually, it creates the array "PARTS" as hoped, however:

```
IFS="/" read -ra PARTS <<< $(pwd)
```

creates an array with a single element, with the slashes converted to spaces

How can I split the current working directory into an array?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.53(3)

Comment: `$ IFS="/" read -ra PARTS <<< $(pwd); printf '%s\n' "${PARTS[@]}"` works great with bash (4.3.30).

Comment: Try IFS="/" read -ra PARTS <<< $(pwd); printf '%s\n' "${#PARTS[@]}" and you'll see that it's only one element

Comment: Why `${#PARTS[@]}` and not `${PARTS[@]}`?

Comment: Putting the # in front of it causes it to print the number of elements in the array. The code that I pasted prints 1, which means that it's not working correctly. In fact, it's doing the exact thing I describe in my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works if you quote the command.

```
IFS="/" read -ra PARTS <<< "$(pwd)"
for i in "${PARTS[@]}"
do
  printf '%s\n' "$i"
done

home
user1
```

Comment: Wow!  This is bizarrely counter-intuitive — you get one word, unless you quote it, and then you get multiple words.  Can anybody explain this?

Comment: @Scott http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: @jasonwryan Well, that looks like a useful reference, but...  I see the example `ip=192.168.1.30` followed by `IFS=. read -ra ip_octets <<< "$ip"`, but I don't see it explained.  Nor does it even emphasize that quoting `$ip` is significant (although I suppose it's implied).  Incidentally, it shows `unset IFS` without explaining what that does or acknowledging the possibility that the user might have had `IFS` set to some non-default value going in.  (I mention this to cast aspersions on the overall quality of the page.)

Comment: @Scott The unset is to restore predictable behaviour. See this page for more on [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Comment: @jasonwryan Sorry, but I don't see anything there that explains this `<<<` behavior.

Comment: @Scott Oh, it's a [herestring](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Heredocs_And_Herestrings).

Comment: @jasonwryan Yes, I know it's a herestring.  I'm looking for an explanation of the behavior where you get one word if it's ***not*** quoted and multiple words if it ***is*** quoted.

Comment: @Scott Perhaps you should ask it as a question?

Answer (score -1):

Since the question is

> How can I split the current working directory into an array?

(and not “How do I get
`IFS="something" read -a arrayname <<< $(command)` to work?”), I give you

```
saveIFS="$IFS"; IFS=/ PARTS=($(pwd)); IFS="$saveIFS"
```

Yeah, I know; it’s ugly.  I tried

```
IFS=/ PARTS=($(pwd))
```

and

and it left `IFS` set to `/`,
even if I enclosed the entire command in `{` … `;}` or used `eval`. 
Naturally, enclosing it in `(` … `)` caused `PARTS`
not to be set in the main shell.

```
IFS=/ declare PARTS=($(pwd))
```

failed even worse.

The first code block (with `saveIFS`) saves the old value of IFS
and restores it (after changing it). 
However, if IFS was previously unset,
the above code sets it to an empty string (commonly called a null string). 
If this is a possibility in your environment,
and you want to be able to restore IFS to not being set,
you can do this:

```
checkIFS="${IFS+1}"
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=/ PARTS=($(pwd))
if [ "$checkIFS" ]
then
    IFS="$saveIFS"
else
    unset IFS
fi
```

(or, all in one line)

```
checkIFS="${IFS+1}"; saveIFS="$IFS"; IFS=/ PARTS=($(pwd)); if [ "$checkIFS" ]; then IFS="$saveIFS"; else unset IFS; fi
```

Here, `checkIFS` is set to 1 if IFS is not set,
and it is set to null if IFS ***is*** set. 
Then it does the obvious test to restore IFS
to its previous (set) / (not set) state,
and to restore its previous value if there was one.

Of course, if you’re very concerned about leaving the environment unchanged
(except for the `PARTS` variable),
you should unset `checkIFS` and `saveIFS`, too.

Comment: What is the value of IFS after this if it was previously unset?

Comment: Good question.  (Interesting timing.) See above.